# What is this thing inside ceilling?

Tags: ceiling, joists

I am trying to figure out whether wall is load bearing or not. 
I am in 2nd floor of 3 storey condominium building.

To figure out which way joists run, I cut rectangle in ceilling near the wall. I can see metal piece behind ceilling drywall as shown in first picture ( along the side of rectangle, facing  bottom right corner of picture). That is definitely not duct work. I placed my cellphone inside and took its picture along it's length.  (2nd picture)

I did find 2x4 or 2x6 running parallel to the wall, around 24 inch away but its wider side is facing toward sky. Is that joist ? I thought joists are placed wider side facing sideways and shorter side facing sky.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a “top hat” rail for attaching Sheetrock. You can see the screw in the pic there should be more. Top hat may be a trade name. But that’s what we called them. Kinda like a metal stud but not as big.

Comment: Takes the place of those old wood furring strips...+

Comment: Hat rail or furring rail is what I heard them called

Comment: Yup I agree with both I have seen them called metal furring and top hat or hat, I guess it may be based on your location in the world.